# MySQL dropdown box query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So my question is kind of confusing.  I'm not a very strong coder.
I hope this makes sense.  This website is someone else's work, so i'm trying to add to it.

I'm trying to make a dropdown box that pulls results from a database.  If anything looks wrong, please tell me.  I cannot seem to get any reults except for a blank dropdown box.

```
(aps2_get_user_role($_SESSION['uid']) == APS_ADMIN) {
                    $return .= '<br/><select>';
                    $selvalue .= 1001;
                    $result5 .= @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aps2_users WHERE role = '1001'");


                    while($urow = @mysql_fetch_array($result5, MYSQL_ARRAY)){
                        $return .= '<option value="test">test</option>';
                        $usrid .= $urow['uid'];
                        $usrname .= $urow['username'];
                        $return .= '<option value="' . $usrid . '">"' . $usrname . '"</option>';
                    }
                $return .= '</select>';
                $return .= $result5;
                }
```

Comment: Why are you using concatenation `.=` everywhere? Do you understand the difference between concatenation and assigning value?

Comment: Nope, I don't know the difference.  That is just what the previous coder left everywhere so I just followed his code.

Comment: Then you should read some manuals and change this piece of code accordingly.

Comment: Wow, that was in no way helpful.  Are you just here to point out others mistakes or help people?

Comment: It's not an answer, so it shouldn't be helpful. But if you don't understand coding basics - nothing to talk about, sorry.

Comment: Well, like the original question says, i'm not a strong coder.  That's why i'm here.

Comment: You mean a user starts typing in the box, and then the page suggests mysql values based on what you typed? If so, you should be using AJAX.

Comment: Lol @u_mulder _"It's not an answer, so it shouldn't be helpful."_... so the comments can be super annoying now?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
(aps2_get_user_role($_SESSION['uid']) == APS_ADMIN) {
    $return = '<br/><select>';
    $result5 = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aps2_users WHERE role = '1001'");

    while($urow = @mysql_fetch_array($result5, MYSQL_ARRAY)){
        $return .= '<option value="test">test</option><option value="'.$urow['uid'].'">"'.$urow['username'].'"</option>';
    }
    return ($return.'</select>');
}
```

But - I don't know what you're trying to achieve with line 1!

You're returning result5 which is the query array in your code which I can't see you'd want. Also assignment versus appending to variables.
You also don't use the $selvalue variable anywhere.

If you're getting no results - ensure those fields you're pulling from the database exist in the table.

Also may be worth posting the code that incorporates the results of this into your HTML page..

Comment: I think line 1 detects whether or not the user is an administrator based on their id. Just a thought though...

Comment: Sorry, the $selvalue was from something i was testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things I notice in above piece of code you should correct it

- `$selvalue .= 1001;` I haven't seen the usage of this variable
- `@` before the `@mysql_query()` is not a good practice why just an
  if else to see the query execution is successful or throws an error
- `$result5 .=@mysql_query(...)` no need of concatenation when
  executing the query result
- `@mysql_fetch_array($result5, MYSQL_ARRAY)` remove `@` and see if it
  throws an error
- `$return .= '<option value="test">test</option>';` is this really
  you need this option in each iteration of the query?
- `$usrid .= $urow['uid']; $usrname .= $urow['username'];` for each
  iteration of the loop the new values will be concatenated with the
  previous one I am sure you don't need that type of output for your
  select box
- The last and main thing `$return .= $result5;` why the result of
  `mysql_query` is appended with the options there is no use of this

---

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).